# How can I reduce my character from sliding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public float jump;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
private void Update()
{
    rb.position += new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    if(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.001f && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jump), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

So I have this code for my player movement. I am wondering how can I reduce my character from sliding that much. I don't want to stop instantly after I release the key.

Comment: Take a look at Physic Material and set its friction to a low value.
Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add counter-movement to make the movement to feel more responsive, or you could change the friction by adding a physics material. Counter-movement makes the player stop by adding a force ***opposite*** to the wanted direction of the movement. It will stop the player from sliding too much. Another approach is to add a physics material and up the friction a bit.  This will make the player stop faster. I hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the Input Manager, `Edit`->`Project Settings`->`Input Manager`, there is a property called `gravity`.

[image]

> **Gravity:** Speed in units per second that the axis falls toward neutral when no input is present.

Decreasing this value will cause the input to fall quicker, resulting in less/no sliding.

You can debug your input value to confirm this.  You should notice a ramp up from 0 to 1/-1 when you first hold the horizontal input.  Once you let go of the input, you should see the value fall back down to 0.

```
var inputHorz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

Debug.Log(inputHorz);
```

Lower the value until it feel correct.  This can be changed while you are playing the game, but you will need to paste that value back in after pressing stop.